# Finding size of largest subtree of a bst contained in a range

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

This was a recent interview question. The question asked to find the size of the largest subtree of a BST contained within a range `[x, y]` were `x < y`. The BST is defined recursively where each node has an integer value, a left child node, and a right child node. I was only able to the total number of nodes in the tree that lie within the range but was not able to find the largest subtree. Here's the code I used, in python:

```
def solution(x, y, T):
    if T is None:
        return 0
    size = 0
    if x < T.val:
        size += solution(x, y, T.left)
    if x <= T.val and y >= T.val:
        size += 1
    # The following if statement was my attempt at resetting the count
    # whenever we find a node outside the range, but it doesn't work
    if x > T.val or y < T.val:
        size = 0
    if B > T.x:
        size += solution(A, B, T.right)
    return size
```

The solution should be `O(N)` where `N` is the number of nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the problem recursively. We need to know the left and the right border of each subtree (that is, the smallest and the largest element). If it lies in range [x, y], we can just update the answer with the total size of the current subtree. Here is some code (the `solution` function returns a tuple with some extra information on top of the answer. If just want it to return the size of the largest subtree in range, you can wrap it around and use it as a helper function).

```
def min_with_none(a, b):
    """
    Returns the minimum of two elements.   
    If one them is None, the other is returned.
    """
    if a is None:
        return b
    if b is None
        return a
    return min(a, b)


def max_with_none(a, b):
    """
    Returns the maximum of two elements.   
    If one them is None, the other is returned.
    """
    if a is None:
        return b
    if b is None:
        return a
    return max(a, b)


def solution(x, y, T):
    """
    This function returns a tuple 
    (max size of subtree in [x, y] range, total size of the subtree, min of subtree, max of subtree) 
    """
    if T is None:
        return (0, 0, None, None)

    # Solves the problem for the children recursively
    left_ans, left_size, left_min, _ = solution(x, y, T.left)
    right_ans, right_size, _, right_max = solution(x, y, T.right)

    # The size of this subtree
    cur_size = 1 + left_size + right_size

    # The left border of the subtree is T.val or the smallest element in the
    # left subtree (if it's not empty)
    cur_min = min_with_none(T.val, left_min)

    # The right border of the subtree is T.val or the largest element in the 
    # right subtree (if it's not empty)
    cur_max = max_with_none(T.val, right_max)

    # The answer is the maximum of answer for the left and for the right 
    # subtree
    cur_ans = max(left_ans, right_ans)
    # If the current subtree is within the [x, y] range, it becomes the new answer,
    # as any subtree of this subtree is smaller than itself
    if x <= cur_min and cur_max <= y:
        cur_ans = cur_size 

    return (cur_size, cur_ans, cur_min, cur_max)
```

This solution clearly runs in linear time as it visits every node only once and performs a constant number of operations per node.

Answer (score 0):

With each node in BST, you can associate a valid range for it say *`[Li,Ri]`*, which implies that all elements in subtree of that node lie in the valid range.

You can easily define these ranges recursively:

For a node *`i`* let's say the range is *`[Li, Ri]`* and the value stored in this node is *`val`*.
For left child of *`i`*, the range is *`[Li, val − 1]`*. And similarly for right child the range is *`[val + 1, Ri]`*.

For root node the valid range is *`[−inf, inf]`*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say our size function returned `-1` for an invalid subtree. A (sub)tree is valid if both the node's value and all the values in its subtrees are in range.

```
# returns a tuple: (size of T, best valid size among itself and its subtrees)
def f(x,y,T): 
  if T is None: 
    return (0,0)

  l_size, l_best = f(x,y,T.left) 
  r_size, r_best = f(x,y,T.right) 

  if x <= T.value <= y and l_size >= 0 and r_size >= 0:
    return (1 + l_size + r_size,1 + l_size + r_size)
  else:
    return (-1,max(l_best,r_best))
```